# I installed the GUI twice

Tags: 14.04, apt

I somewhere read and installed GPU which had asked me for a disk space of some 900Mb. I came to know afterwards that it is nothing but the interface which is installed during installation of OS. What happens if 'apt-get install' is given for already installed package?
Will that eat up my memory space?

Edit from comments: The specific command I used was `sudo apt-get install qt5-default libvtk6-dev`

Comment: No, it can't install more than once.

Comment: Please tell us the specific command you executed. To get a history of all commands you executed, use `history` command.

Answer (score 2):

Tim is correct. Here's what happens if you try this command with a package that is already installed (in this case `vlc`):

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
vlc is already the newest version.
```

Comment: :) Was too busy to write into an answer

Comment: But the OP said it asked for disk space. You are right, but in his context your answer may not be correct.

Comment: @user3073656 he said it asked for disk space during installation, not re-installation. His question was regarding an already installed package. I'm sorry if that wasn't clear. ;-)

Comment: I meant that if the package was installed and was already in the newest version, it would not have asked for disk space. I edited my first comment.

Comment: @user3073656 I thought the intent of the question was clear despite the extraneous information in the first line. Perhaps the OP will shed some light on where one of us misunderstood.

Comment: Thank you for the response. "sudo apt-get install qt5-default libvtk6-dev" was the command used. It said that some of my disk space would be utilized and it took some 3 hours to download something. Im sorry for those "somethings" and "somewheres". Im a new to Linux.

Comment: qt5-default is a small package but depends on some larger ones which would increase the disk space required if you didn't have them: Details http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/qt5-default  libvtk6-dev is a rather large package with a much longer list of dependencies and was a large contributor to time of download and space utilized: Details at http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libvtk6-dev